# Blender removes my fluid simulation cache when rendering. (Help)

Tags: fluid-simulation, cache

I know that this may sound weird. Blender removes the cache I baked for my mantaflow simulation and ends up rendering a "box" type of thing. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is the mesh baked?

Comment: Yes, it is. I even made sure it's baked and tried to run it multiple times, even in a diferent project I get the same issue